# How possible use CTRL+F2 in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I would like to put bookmark in Notepad++. Shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. But on this Windows opens system menu Start. How to fix ?

Comment: Ctrl+F2 has never opened the Start menu in any version of Windows. Check and see if you're using any third-party program that maps keyboard shortcuts to system menus.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the shortcut key to make a bookmark, this is how:

1. Click Settings > Shortcut Mapper
2. Scroll down to where it says Toggle Bookmark (I think its item 54)
3. Double click on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and change it to something like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> whatever you want!
4. Click Okay then click Close.

And tada it should work!

Make sure you don't change it to something windows already has set as a shortcut key though.